# Travis CI Error : No Module name common

Tags: python, django, travis-ci, pytest

I am running my tests on Travis-CI container but the tests seems to be failing with the following output

```
The command "flake8" exited with 0.
0.39s$ py.test --cov
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/bin/py.test", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 47, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 132, in _prepareconfig
    pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 724, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 338, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 333, in <lambda>
    _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 595, in execute
    return _wrapped_call(hook_impl.function(*args), self.execute)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 249, in _wrapped_call
    wrap_controller.send(call_outcome)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 32, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = outcome.get_result()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 279, in get_result
    _reraise(*ex)  # noqa
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 264, in __init__
    self.result = func()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 596, in execute
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 880, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 1030, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 1001, in _preparse
    args=args, parser=self._parser)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 724, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 338, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 333, in <lambda>
    _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 595, in execute
    return _wrapped_call(hook_impl.function(*args), self.execute)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 253, in _wrapped_call
    return call_outcome.get_result()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 279, in get_result
    _reraise(*ex)  # noqa
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 264, in __init__
    self.result = func()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 596, in execute
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py", line 244, in pytest_load_initial_conftests
    dj_settings.DATABASES
  File "/opt/python/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py", line 117, in _handle_import_error
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: No module named common
pytest-django found a Django project in /home/travis/build/corsecotech/corseco-dashboard-web (it contains manage.py) and added it to the Python path.
If this is wrong, add "django_find_project = false" to pytest.ini and explicitly manage your Python path.
The command "py.test --cov" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Can anybody help me to rectify this error. In the earlier build I haven't encountered this error. Just the `py.test --cov` command seems to be given the trouble. 
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Okay. This was pretty simple! Since two devs were working on this thing I just noticed that the settings/common.py file was missing which was causing this error. Haha! Funny though.

I think  I need to get some sleep now.

P.s Fixing `common.py` resolves the issue.